# ArrayList constructor and use in methods

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi I am a novice n just learning java. I was studying ArrayList n came accross this code for example {CODE1}.
I would like to use the same code but add a ArrayListDemo constructor n create methods such as displayList and removeElement.
I tried to find such examples but i did not understand them.

This is the code that i tried {CODE2} With my modifications please tell me where m going wrong.

****CODE1 {Example Code}*******

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AraryListDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    System.out.print("Initial size of al :  " + al.size());
    System.out.print("\n");

    //add.elements to the array list
    al.add("C");
    al.add("A");
    al.add("E");
    al.add("B");
    al.add("D");
    al.add("F");
    al.add(1,"A2");//inserts objects "A2" into array at index 1

    System.out.print("size of al after additions " + al.size());
    System.out.print("\n");

    //display the array list
    System.out.print("contents of al: " +  al );
    System.out.print("\n");

    //Remove elements from the array list
    al.remove("F");
    al.remove(2);

    System.out.print("size of after deletions : " + al.size());
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print("contents of al:" + al);

  }

}
```

*************CODE 2 {My Modifications}********************

```
class ArrayListDemo

{
ArrayList<String> al;//variable declared




ArrayListDemo() throws IOException//try constructor for this
{
    al = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("\n Enter Student Names");
    for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)// will dispaly 
    {
        al.add(br.readLine());
    }



}
void dispList(ArrayList <String> al)
{
    System.out.println("\n Display Student Names");
    for(String str : al)
    {
        System.out.println("\t Name :  "+str+"\n");
    }
}
}
class DisplayArrayList
{
public static void main(String []args) throws IOException
{

    ArrayList <String> al = new ArrayList <String>();
    ArrayListDemo e = new ArrayListDemo();
    e.dispList(al);

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList <String> al = new ArrayList <String>();
ArrayListDemo e = new ArrayListDemo();
e.dispList(al);
```

In the above code, you are creating a new `ArrayList` `al`, and passing the same to `dispList()` method, which doesn't iterate, because the `al` has **no elements**.

I guess you wanted to iterate through the elements which you created within `ArrayListDemo`. So you may want to write `dispList()` method as below, which will now use `ArrayList` defined within the class

```
void dispList() //method parameter "al" is removed now and, al is the al of ArrayListDemo
{
    System.out.println("\n Display Student Names");
    for(String str : al) //here al refers to ArrayList defined within the class
    {
        System.out.println("\t Name :  "+str+"\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what exactly you're asking, but I note that you have a problem with your declarations (plural) of `al`: You have one `ArrayList` named `al` in your `main`, and you have another one that belongs to `ArrayListDemo`. You're reading values into the second one and then printing out the (empty) first one.

You really don't need a separate class with a constructor here. You can just have two `static` methods `readList(List<String> al)` and `dispList(List<String> al)`. If you really do want to have a separate class, pick one place to store the `List` (either in `main` or in the class).

As a note, it's generally a good idea to use the most general type for variables and method parameters that you can. You're declaring an `ArrayList`, which is fine, but if you make your variable and parameters `List`s, your code is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (but not a prefered) solution to make your effort work is to pass the array to the `displist()` method that was filled by the constructor.

```
public static void main(String []args) throws IOException
{
    ArrayListDemo e = new ArrayListDemo();
    e.dispList(e.al);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs as following :-

- `ArrayList <String> al = new ArrayList <String>(); // Initialise an ArrayList of type string`
- `ArrayListDemo e = new ArrayListDemo(); // Initialised  class ArrayListDemo`
- class constructor reads data from user input and add to `ArrayList` `a1` by `br.readLine()`
- `e.dispList(al);` iterates the ArrayList instance `a1` and print its output.